# Woodstox on Android

Tags: java, android, xml, woodstox

I've previously written a library in Java using the native Java 1.6 Stax parser heavily. However, I now want use this library for Android, meaning that this parser is not supported. I'd like to use Woodstox as it implements the Stax 1.0 api and I wouldn't have to rewrite any of my current code, just sub in the dependency.

Android does not have the stax 1 api, so I realize I have to add it. Right now, I've added the woodstox-core-asl-4.2.0.jar, stax-api-1.0-2.jar, and the stax2-api-3.1.3.jar to the classpath. Everything compiles fine, but when I actually try to run an Android application which depends on this library, I get runtime errors indicating it isn't using Woodstox as the implementation for the stax 1 api.

Is there something I'm misunderstanding or doing incorrectly? Am I missing a jar? I've read the [Woodstox help page](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/WoodstoxDownload) thoroughly but can't find anything else I'm missing.

EDIT: I'm starting to wonder if it's actually possible to use Woodstox on Android. The issue is with the dependency on the stax api. After some research I discovered that the Dalvik VM appears to not be ok with those packages being in the javax.* namespace.

Answer (score 0):

How are you passing `XMLInputFactory` / `XMLOutputFactory` instance? Usually it is better to directly construct instances (of `WstxInputFactory`, `WstxOutputFactory`), since there is no real benefit from callign `XMLInputFactory.newInstance()`: at most it adds overhead (much slower, scans classpath).

You are not missing any jars: core and stax2-api are needed always; and if the platform does not include Stax API jar (which Android for some odd reason does not, even tho it is part of JDK 1.6), then that one.

**EDIT**:

Auto-discovery should be based on couple of things:

1. `XMLInputFactory` (etc) check to see if matching system property ("javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory") has value; this is class name of factory to use, if any. So you can set system property with specific impl value
2. If no system property found, see if there is resource `META-INF/services/javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory` to read; one line with class name
3. If neither works, try to create default instance; for J2SE SDK this would be implementation that Oracle provides (Sjsxp)

Woodstox provides SPI information (step 2), to auto-register itself. But since on Android you repackage jars (as Android packages, APK?), it is possible that resource files are either not included, or not found. If this is the root cause, you can still set matching system property. If not, you will need to provide class name or factory instance using other means.

Comment: The whole point for me of using Woodstox was to not have to modify my old code - hence, I'm simply calling XMLInputFactory.newInstance(), not WstxInputFactory. If I can't call these methods (even if yes, it is slower) then Woodstox is not very immediately useful for me. As Woodstox implements this api, why should this be an issue?

Comment: It will work that way if Stax API (from JDK) works correctly on Android; and it definitely works on J2SE/J2EE. It is just that this indirection tends to cause issues without benefits (not just perf, but if you have multiple impls etc); to me better way is to have a single helper method for instantiating `XMLInputFactory`. That method can then either use auto-discovery or direct reference.

Comment: To clarify my answer: I am suggesting that perhaps Stax API auto-discovery has issues on Android. By doing direct instantiation (your library can just take `XMLInputFactory` that caller can provide) you could at least eliminate one problem factor. I edited my answer with bit more information in case it might help resolve the issue.

Comment: I tried what you said and it still has issues. I'm pretty sure this is the issue: It turns out the Dalvik (the android vm) doesn't allow you to use "core" classes (ie javax prefix) from jars. Hence, Woodstox (and lots of others I looked at) will not work out of the box on Android unless they are repackaged. Repacking starts to run into open source issues as it counts as modifying code rather than simply using it. :(

Comment: @EmilyGerner Yes, Android architects have been real boobs in the past, wrt including incomplete (and inconsistent...) subset of `javax` package -- and worse, not allowing inclusion of missing pieces. Based on bug reports (I actually filed one for `javax.xml.stream` few years back) it sounded like either ignorance or arrogance; never knew which one.

But I thought these issues had been resolved for newer Android SDK versions.

Comment: I could be doing something wrong, but it appears they haven't. I tried setting my android version to newest only (to make sure this wasn't an old issue) but I still get the Dalvik 1 error with the really nasty error message about "Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*) when not building a core library." Really sucks. Suggested solution is to repackage code (http://code.google.com/p/dalvik/wiki/JavaxPackages) but this is hacky and has licensing repercussions.